# How can I convert an int to an array of bool?

Tags: c#

How can I convert an int to an array of bool (representing the bits in the integer)? For example:

```
4 = { true, false, false }
7 = { true, true, true }
255 = { true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Int32 number = 10;

var array = Convert.ToString(number, 2).Select(s => s.Equals('1')).ToArray();
```

--Edit--

Using extension method:

```
public static class Int32Extensions
{
    public static Boolean[] ToBooleanArray(this Int32 i)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(i, 2 /*for binary*/).Select(s => s.Equals('1')).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var boolArray = number.ToBooleanArray();
```

Comment: Important to note that this will truncate all leading zeros. I had to pad the front of my bool array until it was length 32.

Answer (score 19):

An `int` should map nicely to `BitVector32` (or `BitArray`)

```
int i = 4;
var bv = new BitVector32(i);
bool x = bv[0], y = bv[1], z = bv[2]; // example access via indexer
```

However, personally I'd just use shifts (`>>` etc) and keep it as an `int`. The `bool[]` would be **much** bigger

Comment: BitVector ... you never know all the classes that are inside the framework ... thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.bitarray.aspx).

```
var bools = new BitArray(new int[] { yourInt }).Cast<bool>().ToArray();
```

Comment: `new int[yourInt]` should be `new int[]{yourInt}`

Comment: If `yourInt` is 255, it will not create an array with the length of eight full of true, or even an array with the length of 32 where the last eight are true, it will create an array with the length of 8160 that is full of false.

Comment: @Guffa: There is a mistake in the code. See @Albin Sunnanbo comment. If we rectify to @Albin's comment then the array size is 32.

Comment: Not really a bug, just a difference in behaviour. Most collections allow you to `new(size)` which is exactly what it's doing with the `int` constructor. That said it bit me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a two-step process, first convert the integer to a binary (base 2) string representation using [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kwkfdz.aspx) and then iterate over that string to populate a [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

For example:

```
int someInt = 7;
string binaryString = Convert.ToString(someInt, 2); 
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(binaryString.Length); 
for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
{
    bitArray[i] = (binaryString[i] == '1');
}
```

Comment: `BitArray` has a constructor taking an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static bool[] Convert(int[] input, int length)
    {
        var ret = new bool[length];
        var siz = sizeof(int) * 8;
        var pow = 0;
        var cur = 0;

        for (var a = 0; a < input.Length && cur < length; ++a)
        {
            var inp = input[a];

            pow = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < siz && cur < length; ++i)
            {
                ret[cur++] = inp > 0 ? (inp & pow) != 0 : (inp & pow) == 0;

                pow *= 2;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This answer could use some narrative. Why is 'input' an array of integers?

Comment: @kccricket the topic author asked. int[] to bool[]

Comment: @nim The author asked for "How can I convert _an int_ to an array of bool?", not "How can I convert _an array of int_ to an array of bool?". The examples in the question are also single ints, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BitArray` to easily get a collection of booleans from a number:

```
var b = new BitArray(new int[] { 255 });
```

However, it will use all the bits in the value, so the above will get you a `BitArray` with the length 32 as the `int` data type is 32 bits.

You can create a `BitArray` from bytes, which would give you eight booleans from each byte:

```
var b = new BitArray(new byte[] { 255 });
```

You can get an array with only the significant bits by skipping the leading falses:

```
bool[] b = new BitArray(42).Cast<bool>().SkipWhile(x => !x).ToArray();
```