# Convert uint64_t Bitmask to std::array of bool

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, gcc, stdarray

The objective is to convert a `std::uint64_t` (which is used as a bitmask), to a `std::array<bool>`.

This question is similar to the C# question [How can I convert an int to an array of bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448063/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-array-of-bool), but for C++ and I'm looking for the algorithm with the **bestest performance**.

Given a `std::uint64_t`, which is used as a bitmask, I know it is possible to just loop over its content bitwise & bitcompare set the values to the ones at the same position in the `std::array<bool>`.

But in almighty C++ there **has** to be a more efficient way! Maybe some dirty casts, mallocs or whatnot? Everything is ok; I am on Windows / GCC, so even GCC-only features are totally allowed.

Comment: ...even inline asm is ok

Comment: Do you really need a `std::array<bool>`?  You could convert the bitmask to a `std::bitset` to get random access to the individual bits.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sounds ok to me, but boring

Comment: There's no cast that's going to take you from 64 bits to 64 bytes, assuming that's what a bool is on your system. bitset is likely the better way to go here. Is there a particular problem you're trying to solve? It seems to me the best performance would be to keep your uint64_t and extract the bits you need when you need them.

Comment: If you're targeting x86, you might be able to use some of the vector instructions (AVX?) to store parts of a word into different targets.  Not sure about other ISAs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need random access to the individual bits you can use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of a `std::array`.  That would look like

```
uint64_t mask = some_value;
std::bitset<64> random_access(mask);

// and now you can use random_access[some_index]
```

`std::bitset` does lack `begin()` and `end()` members though, so you can't use it with a ranged based `for` loop as-is.  You can however iterate over a `std::bitset` using a regular index based for loop like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < random_access.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << random_access[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: If I had known there exists such a simple (and thus boring) solution I hadn't troubled asking :'(

Comment: @nada Sorry, sometimes C++ just gives you what you want ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question in OP.