# Converting an Interger to a bool List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, binary, int, boolean

I have a Number Stored in in shared preferences. This Number is a converted Binary Number that represents the State of a few user-changable checkboxes.

```
false false false false => 0000 => 0
false false false true => 0001 => 1
false false true false => 0010 => 2
false false true true => 0011 => 3
false true true true => 0111 => 7
true true true true => 1111 => 15
```

I managed to convert this List to the Integer, but am not able to do it the other way arround.

I just need a solution like this one [stackoverflow.com/questions/4448063/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-array-of-bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448063/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-array-of-bool) but in Dart. Because I'm very new to Dart, I have trouble reaching a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk a single 1 down the bitmask, logically ANDing it with the bitmask.

```
void main() {
  print(asBools(7, 4)); // prints [false, true, true, true]
}

/// Convert a bitmap to a [List] of [bool]s.
/// 
/// [val] is the bitmap, [bits] is the number of relevant bits and therefore
/// the length of the returned list.
/// 
/// Assumes the bits are in the least significant bits of [val].
List<bool> asBools(int val, int bits) {
  var list = List<bool>(bits);
  var mask = 1 << (bits - 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < bits; i++, mask >>= 1) {
    list[i] = val & mask != 0;
  }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can do that for you:

```dart
import 'dart:math';


int boolArrayToDecimal(List<bool> items) => 
  items.asMap().map<int,int>((k,v)=>MapEntry(k,v?pow(2,items.length-k-1):0)).values.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);



void main() {
  print(boolArrayToDecimal([true,true,false,false])); //outputs 12
}
```